# Get primary key value of selected row item in DataGrid using WPF

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, advanceddatagrid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a `DataGrid`, bound to database table `customer`.

I need to select the primary key `ID` value from database table of selected row in DataGrid.

How to do it ? please Help ..

Comment: Hope this question is clear !

Comment: Are you using `ORM` framework? Entity Framework? NHibernate?

Comment: I am not using any framework until now.... i am simply making database(sqlite) driven application using wpf controls ...

Comment: Upload your code of how you bind grid to the database

Comment: sqlitecon.Open();
                string Query = "Select Card_Number,Clients_Title,Address_Current,Phone_Number,Mobile_Number from Customer_New  ";
                SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqlitecon);
                createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdp = new SQLiteDataAdapter(createCommand);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Customer_New");
                dataAdp.Fill(dt);
                datagrid_cindex.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                dataAdp.Update(dt);
                sqlitecon.Close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `ID` to the select statement

```
string Query = "Select ID,Card_Number,Clients_Title,Address_Current,Phone_Number,Mobile_Number from Customer_New ";
```

Since you want to hide the `ID` column, and your columns are generated automatically, register to the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event of your grid

```
datagrid_cindex.AutoGeneratingColumn += OnAutoGenetingColumns;
```

In `OnAutoGenetingColumns`, hide the ID column

```
private void OnAutoGenetingColumns(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "ID")
        e.Column.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

When you want to retreive the ID of the selected row, use:

```
var selectedRow = datagrid_cindex.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
var id = selectedRow["ID"];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: On a side-note I must say that your really should use some ORM framework. Binding the UI directly to the Database is a very tight coupling that you normally would want to avoid ...

Comment: Thanks .....This is working 100%.....Can you share with me some good link of tutorial or Video tutorial for learning ORM framework from start to end  ....

Comment: I use [NHibernate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21122/NHibernate-Made-Simple) with [FluentNHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) configuration as [ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend). [This](http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/02/20/Linq-to-NHibernate-Tutorial.aspx) is a great tutorial to get you started. If my post answered your question, please mark it as _answered_. thank you :)

Comment: This seems very clumsy considering most grids provide either an actual row property that is the PK, or a global property for the name of the row PK.

Comment: @ProfK But wouldn't that be a case only if you are using `EF`, `ORM`, etc. It's not clear what data binding mechanism  `OP` is using.